# Getting error when I try to run a docker image on Windows Server 2016 created on Windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2016, docker-image, docker-for-windows

I have created an image from cmd for a Wcf self hosted service created with Visual Studio 2017 ,  on my machine(Windows 10, update 1709) with Docker for Windows and I save it on local:

```
docker build -t myimage:self-hosted.
docker save -o my_image.tar my_image
```

I have copied on other machine which has Windows server 2016 (update 1607).I have loaded it:

```
docker load -i my_image.tar
```

And when I want to run it I get the following error:

```
docker run my_image
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: container
>   b22d4e399d6ad30d58b1d0bbd7e3421101ec299e56f1e83f446642602bcc7dc7
>   encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows
>   system call: The operating system of the container does not match the
>   operating system of the host. (0xc0370101) extra info:
>   {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"b22d4e399d6ad30d58b1d0bbd7e3421101ec299e56f1e83f446642602bcc7dc7","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\?\Volume{d5a9f60e-8fde-11e8-a9c3-aac9799581d5}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\b22d4e399d6ad30d58b1d0bbd7e3421101ec299e56f1e83f446642602bcc7dc7","Layers":[{"ID":"6f6efbbe-ed91-5913-a9ec-2504016e0138","Path":"C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\e8e0942c7773e994fc13088ae99957d7e6f9980cac27516a992a27d5105f6c88"}],"HostName":"b22d4e399d6a","HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["667cf96b-593d-4ef8-94b1-3812c6528da5"],"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}

Can you tell me what's wrong?

On my machine the created container is working .
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can not run 1709 images on Windows 1607. Check details here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility